# How to deploy an ASP.NET Core mvc app locally on a Mac, and re-deploy on build

Tags: macos, deployment, localhost, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-mac

I got this situation where I am developing an ASP.NET Core MVC application on my Mac using Visual Studio for mac.

Everytime I hit run, the web project does everything it needs to do, it is hosted on the localhost.
But I would like to have the same environment that one can have on Windows. Being that you configure your application to be "hosted" on the local IIS and whenever you build your web project, it is automatically published to that local IIS. This way you can keep writing your code, and when you want to test it out (and not want to debug it) you just rebuild your solution and the web project is published to the local IIS where you directly can test the newly written functionality. Without needing to "start" the web project.

Does anyone have experience with this on the new Visual Studio for Mac ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a way to deploy my ASP.NET Core website on Mamp (developing on a Mac).

Right now, for testing purpose, I need to run 2 visual studio instance (command line to open a second visual studio on mac : in terminal, open -n -a "Visual Studio").

Then run the ASP.NET in one solution, and run your iOS / Android project in the second visual studio instance.
Quite boring.

Also, I'm still looking how to select a profile on Visual Studio Mac. In visual studio, I can run my IIS Express profile, my swagger profile etc. How to specify that on Mac ??

Thanks for any help !! Good luck every one.